# Android: How to scroll header to top when there is no/limited items in ListView?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I'm developing an Android app in which I added a header view in ListView.
Now I want that header view is displayed only when a user scrolls down the
ListView. I tried following, but was not successful to achieve required output.

- listView.setSelection(1) works well but only when the data size is
  above the viewable area, i.e. ListView is scrollable.
- android:scrollY is giving the required UI output but scroll down of
  list view  is not smooth for header, i.e. search bar comes down with
  jerk.

I need the same behavior even when there is only one item in list. But when data in list
is limited, the header is always visible.

[image]

Any suggestion(s) will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Ammar

Comment: You could explain it better with an image?

Comment: @Nun'e Chai, image shared

Comment: You said "I need the same behavior even when there is only one item in list." but then you said "when data in list is limited, the header is always visible." Can you explain it a bit more? These two statements seems to go against each other.

Answer (score 0):

This effect can be achieved easily with a simple trick, make sure to include `compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:20.0.0'` in `build.gradle` or if you are on Eclipse then download latest support jar file:

Use following xml layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pullToShowBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/searchBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-48dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="My Hidden Search Bar" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

This is your `Activity`s code:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    final View searchBar = findViewById(R.id.searchBar);
    final SwipeRefreshLayout sw = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.pullToShowBar);
    sw.setColorSchemeColors(Color.TRANSPARENT, Color.TRANSPARENT, Color.TRANSPARENT, Color.TRANSPARENT);
    sw.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            sw.setRefreshing(false);
            ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams layoutParams = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) searchBar.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            searchBar.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
    });
}
}
```

One last piece:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.AbsListView;


public class PullToSearchBarLayout extends SwipeRefreshLayout {
private AbsListView mListView;

public PullToSearchBarLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public PullToSearchBarLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}


@Override
public boolean canChildScrollUp() {
    if (mListView == null) {
        mListView = (AbsListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    }
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 14) {
        final AbsListView absListView = mListView;
        return absListView.getChildCount() > 0
                && (absListView.getFirstVisiblePosition() > 0 || absListView.getChildAt(0)
                .getTop() < absListView.getPaddingTop());
    } else {
        return ViewCompat.canScrollVertically(mListView, -1);
    }
}
}
```